Production CM deployment to staging slot is failing at unicorn sync script execution in Azure PaaS
we are using Sitecore 9.3.0 and Unicorn 4.1.1. During our production cm deployment Unicorn sync script is failing intermittently.
Below is the error from the log

2024-06-27T02:30:19.8857407Z ## Initializing Azure Complete
2024-06-27T02:30:19.8874143Z ## Beginning Script Execution
2024-06-27T02:30:19.9508480Z ##[command]& 'D:\a\r1\a\AzureProdCM\deployment\UnzipPackage\Unicorn\Sync.ps1' https://##-##-##-cm-staging.azurewebsites.net/unicorn.aspx D:\a\r1\a/AzureProdCM/deployment/UnzipPackage/Unicorn
2024-06-27T02:30:20.0740747Z Sync-Unicorn: Preparing authorization for https://##-##-##-p-cm-staging.azurewebsites.net/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&configuration=
2024-06-27T02:30:25.5259363Z Sync-Unicorn: Received challenge: 03d238dab50f48ffaa3d2f1f9994b237
2024-06-27T02:30:25.5339064Z Sync-Unicorn: Created signature rvVxIf1DaJe5bM3dBt2Pt8SWlUH8bDdKSJGreDsrnzkipb/3wr2dCJRLUujhv/I1XmQlgSkXYnX7nflqCgFZXA==, executing Sync...
2024-06-27T02:34:45.8546847Z ##[error]Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

When restart the webapp and re-deploy the package again it will succeed, but it will take 1 and half hours for each deployment. So, its bit challenging.
Any ideas on where to look would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
